# How to correctly use FirefoxOptions() and its arguments to pass it to the FirefoxDriver() constructor

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, arguments, selenium-firefoxdriver

I'm trying to use FirefoxOptions when instantiating a FirefoxDriver like below:

```
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
WebDriver localWebDriver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
```

I've been looking around in the web on how to correctly use FirefoxOptions similar to when using ChromeOptions, **and mainly a list of arguments to pass to the FirefoxOptions**, but had no luck in this search.

An example of how to use ChromeOptions with ChromeDriver is as follows:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
options.addArguments("--kiosk");
options.addArguments("--ignore-certificate-errors");
options.addArguments("--disable-popup-blocking");
options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
options.addArguments("--incognito");
WebDriver webDriver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

**Does anyone know how to use FirefoxOptions correctly, and a list of arguments that can be passed to it?**

Comment: Are you seeing any error with the second code block?

Comment: None. Is there a reason I should see one?

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing something like this

```
const defaultFireFoxFlags = [
            // '--headless',
            "--disable-gpu",
            // "--window-size=1280x1696", // Letter size'--no-sandbox',
            "--user-data-dir=/tmp/user-data",
            "--hide-scrollbars",
            "--enable-logging",
            "--log-level=0",
            "--v=99",
            "--single-process",
            "--data-path=/tmp/data-path",
            "--ignore-certificate-errors",
            "--homedir=/tmp",
            "--disk-cache-dir=/tmp/cache-dir",
            "--start-maximized"
          ];
          const geckoDriverPath = path.join(__dirname, "../assets/geckodriver");
          const firefoxServiceBuilder = new firefox.ServiceBuilder(geckoDriverPath);
          const firefoxOptions = new firefox.Options();
          defaultFireFoxFlags.forEach(flag => firefoxOptions.addArguments(flag));
          if (webDriverInitOptions.headless) firefoxOptions.headless();
          this.driver = new Builder()
            .forBrowser(webDriverInitOptions.browser)
            .setFirefoxService(firefoxServiceBuilder)
            .setFirefoxOptions(firefoxOptions)
            .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR - FirefoxOptions with a list of arguments 2023**

```
FirefoxOptions firefoxOptions = new FirefoxOptions();
firefoxOptions.addArguments(List.of("arg1", "arg2", "arg3"));

// instantiate the webdriver session
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxOptions);
```

Make sure to also read the [official selenium docs for Firefox](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/browsers/firefox/)!

---

**Some more details and explanation**

Not sure if the question is still relevant in 2023 but since it hasn't been answered yet:

The basic usage of FirefoxOptions according to the [official java docs](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/firefox/FirefoxOptions.html):

```
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions()
  .addPreference("browser.startup.page", 1)
  .addPreference("browser.startup.homepage", "https://www.google.co.uk");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
```

However, what I frequently do when running tests is this:

```
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();

// these affect the browser startup command when run by the selenium instance
options.addArguments("--headless");

FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();

// these allow modifying variables usually seen in page about:config of Firefox
profile.setPreference("general.useragent.override", "some test user agent");

// activate custom firefox options
options.setProfile(profile);

// instantiate the webdriver session
WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(selenium_host), firefoxOptions);
```

If you want to add these arguments as a list you could just use something like:

```
options.addArguments(List.of("arg1", "arg2", "arg3"));
```

Their API supports this nowadays.

Answer (score -2):

FirefoxOptions can be added following way:

```
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
        options.setBinary("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla\\Firefox\\firefox.exe");
 WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
```

If you look at the [documentation](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/firefox/FirefoxOptions.html), there are the arguments for each of the methods for `FirefoxOptions`.

Answer (score -2):

Link to preferences list: http://kb.mozillazine.org/About:config_entries

```
case BrowserType.Firefox:
                {
                    var service = FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
                    var options = new FirefoxOptions();
                    options.SetPreference("permissions.default.image", 2);
                    driver = new FirefoxDriver(service, options);
                    break;
                }
```

e.g. with C# code

Comment: Chrome: options.addArguments("--incognito"); Firefox: options.addArguments("-private");